# Mid and Len causes Invalid Procedure Call or Argument 5

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to split keywords from a column. However, it keeps throwing me the subject error. I suspect this is to do with my Len or Mid.

```
Sub ConcatenateTLS()

  Dim x As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim colLen As Integer

  On Error GoTo ER

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

  x = InputBox("Enter your Column Label")

  LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LR
        colLen = Len(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) - 20
        If colLen <> 0 Then
            ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = Mid((ws.Cells(i, 1).Value), 15, colLen)
        End If

    Next
ER:
  MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `colLen = Len(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) - 20`
I'd imagine that you could be having issues where `colLen` can be a negative number. If that is the case, you could fix it by changing the If statement to `If colLen > 0 Then`.

Comment: It can also be useful to use the intermediate window to help work out these things, such as what values it's crashing on. You could type `Debug.Print colLen` inside the loop and in the intermediate window `Ctrl+G` or `View > Intermediate Window` (in the IDE) it'll print out the value each time. A very useful tool.

Comment: Hi So the purpose of ColLen is to cut keyword out of a string on column A

Comment: What kind of behavior do you want when the length of the value in the cell is less than 20?

Comment: Basically to simply move to the next object in this case the next row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a negative number, colLen, to the MID function. Try adding some conditional handling to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative:

```
Sub M_snb()
  On Error Resume Next
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(InputBox("which column ?")).Name = "snb_002"

  MsgBox Join(Filter([transpose(if(snb_002="","~",if(len(snb_002)>20,left(snb_002,len(snb_002)-20),snb_002)))], "~", False), vbLf)
End Sub
```